# Content appears below sidebar when using Next.js layouts

Tags: next.js, layout, sidebar, mantine

I'm using mantine.dev to create a sidebar component for my app, and im using next.js layouts to make sure it appears on every page. the links work fine, but the actual page content appears BELOW the sidebar, and not beside it. like in the image:
[Application set to test page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQdYn.png)

This is the navbar component:

```
export function NavbarSimple() {
  const { classes, cx } = useStyles();
  const [active, setActive] = useState('Dashboard');

  const items = data.map((item, index) => (   
    <Link href={item.link} passHref style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}>
      <NavLink
        style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}
        key={item.label}     
        // @ts-ignore
        active={index === active} 
        label={item.label}
        icon={<item.icon size={16} stroke={1.5} />}
        // @ts-ignore
        onClick={() => setActive(index)}

      />   
    </Link>
  ));

  return (
    <Navbar height='100vh' width={{ sm: '28vh' }} p="md" zIndex={0}>
      <Navbar.Section grow>
        <Group className={classes.header} position="apart">         
          <Code sx={{ fontWeight: 700 }}>0.1</Code>
        </Group>
        {items}
      </Navbar.Section>
     
{/* Bottom section Here \/ */}

      <Navbar.Section className={classes.footer}>
        <a href="#" className={classes.item} onClick={(event) => event.preventDefault()}>
          <IconSwitchHorizontal className={classes.linkIcon} stroke={1.5} />
          <span>Change account</span>
        </a>

        <a href="#" className={classes.item} onClick={(event) => event.preventDefault()}>
          <IconLogout className={classes.linkIcon} stroke={1.5} />
          <span>Logout</span>
        </a>
      </Navbar.Section>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
```

This is the layout:

```
import { NavbarSimple } from "./Navbar/Navbar";



export default function Layout({ children }) {
    return (
      <>
        <NavbarSimple />
        <main>{children}</main>
          
        
      </>
    )
  }
```

I've tried using mantine's appshell component and using the navbar inside it, but im not really sure how i can make the page changes when using the appshell, and it re-renders the entire page when using it so im using next.js layouts but it doesnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
export default function Layout({ children }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div
                style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    flexDirection: "row"
                }}
            >
                <NavbarSimple />
                <div
                    style={{
                        width: "100%"
                    }}
                >
                    <main>{children}</main>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your Page and navbar are two different components and layout.js will render the navbar above each page as provided in your code. If you want your content to render beside the navbar component then you need to provide `position: relative/absolute`(accordingly) & `zIndex:10`. It worked for me;

Try this CSS on your Navbar component;

```
position: absolute/relative;
z-index: 10;
```